# Encode data in PHP

Tags: php

I am fetching data from the textarea and encoding it using the below syntax

`<?php trim(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($str_value), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));?>`

But when user copied data from email or from Microsoft word or any other editor some characters can not encoding it.
for example `–,”,“,’,‘`

Specifically Mozilla convert it into some characters but in chrome it breaks string and string  becomes blank

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems copied chars does not encoded correctly to UTF. You can try this

```
trim(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(mb_convert_encoding($str_value, "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($str_value))), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))
```